# Spring cloud stream binder - Invalid bean definition

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-stream, azure-eventhub

I am using:
`some-eventhub.some-service-1.errors` in my application's Service Activator to listen to the error channel.

Stream binder 1.2.8 and Spring boot 2.2.2

I get the below exception messages frequently in my app:-

```
Invalid bean definition with name 'some-eventhub.some-service-1.errors.recoverer' defined in null: Cannot register bean definition 
[Root bean: class [org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.ErrorMessageSendingRecoverer]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=null; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null] for bean 'some-eventhub.some-service-1.errors.recoverer': There is already [Root bean: class [org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.ErrorMessageSendingRecoverer]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=null; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null] bound.
```

Comment: Not sure if this is your exact problem, but maybe take a look at this [github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/1905](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/1905#issuecomment-585816343)

Comment: I did see that thread, but unfortunately it ends abruptly.

Answer (score 0):

It is because it keeps trying to register an error channel recoverer which has already been registered. You probably have more than one binding to the same error topic ("some-eventhub") by the same consumer group ("some-service-1").

Comment: I to get the exact  error. I followed the sample described here      
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-spring-boot-samples/tree/main/servicebus/azure-spring-cloud-stream-binder-servicebus-topic/servicebus-topic-binder